# Change color of NSTableViewCell

Tags: cocoa, background-color, nstableviewcell

How can I change the color of a cell in my NSTableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a custom `NSView` for that, or `NSTableView`'s `-setBackgroundColor:` method.

Comment: NSTableView setBackgroundColor accomplishes nothing with regards to setting the color of the NSTableViewCell.

Comment: This is a completely incorrect answer. It doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 14):

In your `NSTableViewDelegate` for the `NSTableView`, implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(id)cell 
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
              row:(NSInteger)row
```

The `NSTableView` calls this on its delegate before displaying each cell so that you can affect its appearance.  Assuming you're using NSTextFieldCells, for the cell that you want to change  call:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:...];
```

Or, if you want to change the text color:

```
[cell setTextColor:...];
```

If you want columns to have different appearances, or if all of the columns aren't NSTextFieldCells, use `[tableColumn identifier]` to, er, identify the column.  You can set the identifier in Interface Builder by selecting the table column.

Comment: Make sure `drawsBackground` is enabled on the NSTextFieldCell otherwise this will have no effect!

Comment: This only works for NSCell based tables, not NSView ones @MiguelCarvajal

Answer (score 2):

// TESTED - Swift 3 solution...for changing color of cell text in a single column. All columns in my tableview have a unique identifier

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        let myCell:NSTableCellView = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn?.identifier)!, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        if tableColumn?.identifier == "MyColumn" {
            let results = arrayController.arrangedObjects as! [ProjectData]
            let result = results[row]
            if result.ebit < 0.0 {
                myCell.textField?.textColor = NSColor.red
            } else {
                myCell.textField?.textColor = NSColor.black
            }
        }
        return myCell
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method to change the background color of the ```cellView.textField?.backgroundColor = NSColor.yellow``` but it doesn't work.  How would I change your answer to make this work for the background color?  I also tried applying a backgroundFilter to the cellView itself ```cellView.backgroundFilters.append(highlightFilter)``` but that only changes the text color to yellow.  My filter is set as ```let highlightFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIFalseColor")!``` then ```let highlightCIColor = CIColor(red: 0.9608, green: 0.9765, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)``` (continued)...

Comment: and finally in ```viewDidLoad()``` I set the filter ```highlightFilter.setValue(highlightCIColor, forKey: "inputColor1")```.  But as I wrote in my previous comment this only turns the text color yellow and not the background of the cellView.  I want to be able to change the individual cell background.  Changing the textColor works fine, as expected.

Comment: this is technically wrong, because it is for View based Tables, not for Cell based!

Answer (score 1):

```
//for VIEW based TableViews using Objective C
//in your NSTableViewDelegate, implement the following
//this customization makes the column numbers red if negative.
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)inTableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *result = nil;
    if ([tableColumn.title isEqualToString: @"Amount"]) {
        //pick one of the following methods to identify the NSTableCellView
        //in .xib file creation, leave identifier "blank" (default)
         result = [inTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
        //or set the Amount column's NSTableCellView's identifier to "Amount"
        result = [inTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"Amount" owner:self];
        id aRecord = [[arrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
        //test the relevant field's value
        if ( aRecord.amount < 0.0 )
            [[result textField] setTextColor:[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
    } else {
        //allow the defaults to handle the rest of the columns
        result = [inTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    }
    return result;
}
```