# Set Background colour on NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to set a background colour on an NSTableCellView, but there doesn't seem to be an way to do this.

Therefor there must be another way to achieve this that i am not aware of, so, if anyone could enlighten me i would be most appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879154/change-color-of-nstableviewcell

Comment: Actually, the question suggested as a dupe is about setting the colour of an `NSTableViewCell` (subclass of `NSCell`), while the question is about the colour of an `NSTableCellView` (subclass of `NSView`). Two different things! When the old question was asked, view based tables did not exist in Cocoa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `NSTableCellView` *is a* `NSView`, and a `NSView` *has a* `CALayer`, and a `CALayer` *has a* `backgroundColor`. So...

```
myTableCellView.wantsLayer = YES;  // make the cell layer-backed
myTableCellView.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor redColor] CGColor]; // or whatever color you like
```

Comment: @Caleb does anything need to be enabled on the tableview in interface builder to get this working? Its not working for me. XCode6

Comment: @Jai A layer's background color needs to be a CGColor, so the above should probably be `...[[NSColor redColor] CGColor];`. I know that's the case on iOS, and from the docs it looks like the same situation on MacOS X.

Comment: @Jai I had to enable layer with `myTableCellView.wantsLayer = true`

Comment: A `NSView` **does not** have a `CALayer` by default. It will only have a `CALayer` if you explicitly tell it to have a `CALayer` (if you make it layer backed or layer hosting). Also your code sample is wrong as you assign a `NSColor` to a property of type `CGColor` (yields a compiler warning at built time and fails to work at runtime - won't even compile if you try that in Swift).

Comment: @Mecki Thanks for your comments. Edited to fix the color problem. yuzer's comment above points out that you need to add a layer as well -- I'll include that edit too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your NSColor object into a CGColor struct:

```
self.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor redColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 3, and based on Caleb's answer, this works for me:

```
cell.wantsLayer = true
cell.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

It took me ages to find this question and answer, and I'm most appreciative.