# NSTableCellView *result change the text color according to the logic

Tags: objective-c, nstablecellview

i have a custom class "size" as object for a RestFull call. The result populates an array controlled by a NSArrayController. Then the TableView will bound to this controller in IB. All work as apected. What i would achieve is change color in NSViewCell based on sizes. Ex: Size "M" will be Red, "S" will be green, and "XXL" Brown.

.h

```
@interface RecordSize : NSObject  
@property (readwrite, retain) NSString *key;
@property (readwrite, retain) NSString *size;
-(id)initWithName:(NSDictionary *)row;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "RecordSize.h"

@implementation RecordSize
@synthesize key = _key, size = _size;

-(id)initWithName:(NSDictionary *)row {  
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {       
        _key = [row valueForKey:@"id"];
        _size = [row valueForKey:@"text"];       
    }
    return self;    
}
@end
```

delegate class constructor:

```
- (id)init {

        if (self) {
            self  = [super init];

            //*********** TableViev
            NSString * urlString = @"http://xxxxx/restfull/size/";

            RestateC *restSize = [[RestateC alloc]initWithName:urlString];
            //add Delegate

            restSize.delegate = self;

            NSArray*  aTmp = [restSize syncronize];
            NSMutableArray *thingSize = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            for (NSDictionary *row in aTmp)
            {
                RecordSize *item = [[RecordSize alloc] initWithName:row];
                [thingsSize addObject: item ];
            }
            self.aRecordSize = thingsRecordSize;

            _sizeTableView.delegate = self;
        }
        return self;
}
```

method fro NSTablecolumn in a view based cell

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{

    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
       if( [[tableColumn identifier] isEqual:@"AGONIA"] ) {
           NSLog(@"IDENTITY %@", [tableColumn identifier]);

        if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"M"]) {
            result.textField.textColor = [NSColor redColor];
        }

        if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"S"]) {
            result.textField.textColor = [NSColor greenColor];
        }

         if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"XXL"]) {
            result.textField.textColor = [NSColor brownColor];
        }

    }
    else  result.textField.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];

    return result;
}
```

so the method was call correctly from delegate but the logic does not work.

Any help is largely wellcome.

Comment: When you say the logic does not work, what does it look like instead? Black?

Comment: yes black! In tablecolumn there is the values "M", "S", "XXL" but the color still remain Black.

Comment: Below `NSLog(@"IDENTITY %@"`, can you just log `[result.textField stringValue]`, just to make sure it goes through the logic?

Comment: Thank you for support Enrico. NSLog(@"RESULT %@", [result.textField stringValue]); was empty

Comment: Cool, now you should be able to fix this.

Comment: I'm investigating this...
The odd behavior is that i can find tablecolumn identify and set the color to all column identified.
But, i can't find values inside the tablecolumn cellview.  
Maybe the delegate call such method before populated by datasource.

As cocoabuilder.com answer:
The view is just there do display values,
not provide them. You have "the true" values in your model object.

This suggestion makes me think to use NSAttributeString...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was arrived. The mistake initially come from search the values in NSTableCellView *result. The results don't contain any values: they are there only for display the values.

finally:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];

    if( [[tableColumn identifier] isEqual:@"SizeColumn"] ) {

        if ([[[_arrayInstance valueForKeyPath:@"sizes"]objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"M"]) {
            NSLog(@"FIND: %@", [[_arrayInstance valueForKeyPath:@"sizes"]objectAtIndex:row]);
            [result.textField setTextColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
            return result;
        }
        if ([[[_arrayInstance valueForKeyPath:@"sizes"]objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"XXL"]) {
            NSLog(@"FIND: %@", [[_arrayInstance valueForKeyPath:@"testo"]objectAtIndex:row]);
            [result.textField setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
            return result;
        }

    }

    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hope help someone. I did google for two day but notingh useful found.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with NSAttributedString too.

Comment: Hi sheen and TY! in the middle of  the night I got the same idea! i will tray... Hope i ll accept you answer...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set background color to NSTableCellView - you should use following interface.

```
NSColor *bgcolor = nil;
        if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"M"]) {
            bgcolor = [NSColor redColor];
        }

        if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"S"]) {
            bgcolor = [NSColor greenColor];
        }

         if ([[result.textField stringValue] isEqualToString :@"XXL"]) {
            bgcolor = [NSColor brownColor];
        }
    result.layer.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
```

Ref [Set Background colour on NSTableCellView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794868/set-background-colour-on-nstablecellview)

In your code you tried to color text in cell - it is right requirement for you -- I can not see you setting text to the cell.

Comment: Thank you! I need coloring text no background. You suggestion is very interesting. But setTextColor is for "cell base" and not for "view based" tableview. but i try.

Comment: Im sorry, cliccked down vote for mistake. when i can change i will